# Pytest is incorrectly handling string literals with accented characters

Tags: utf-8, pytest, string-literals

When I run this code:

```
assert len("mas") == 3
assert len("más") == 3
```

inside a regular Python program (using 3.8.10), it works as expected and all
assertions pass.  However, when I put the same code into a pytest like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def test_my_bug():
    assert len("mas") == 3
    assert len("más") == 3
```

the second assertion fails because it thinks the string has length 4.  This is
clearly some kind of confusion between bytes and unicode points, but it works
fine in regular python.  Is there a way to fix this in pytest?

I can work
around this problem by using Python's unittest instead, but I prefer the more concise syntax
used by pytest.

If you remove the "utf-8" line in the pytest file, it blows
up badly, which is already something of a red flag for me.

In my real code,
there are dozens of places where the "test code" passes a literal into the "real code being tested" which
then pulls out substrings, so the key is to get the literal constructed correctly in
the test code.  And as you might have guessed, I'm working with Spanish strings so
there is no choice about whether to use accents.

UPDATE:

I just realized that I reported the version of python, but not the version of pytest.  When I looked that up it was old so I updated to a newer version (7.1.2) and now my test works fine.  I didn't realize that the standard Ubuntu install was so far behind (still on 4.6.9).  Problem solved; sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

`á` can be represented as one Unicode code point (U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE) or two (U+0061 U+00301 LATIN SMALL LETTER A and COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT).  They appear visually the same.  Make sure you haven't generated the wrong version.  Did you cut and paste the *exact same code* from the working script to the non-working pytest?

```py
>>> s1 = '\u00e1'
>>> s2 = '\u0061\u0301'
>>> s1
'á'
>>> s2
'á'
>>> s1 == s2
False
>>> len(s1)
1
>>> len(s2)
2
```

Use `ascii()` to see the difference:

```py
>>> print(ascii(s1))
'\xe1'
>>> print(ascii(s2))
'a\u0301'
```

In this case you can force the combining or decomposed forms if needed:

```py
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> print(ascii(ud.normalize('NFC','más')))
'm\xe1s'
>>> print(ascii(ud.normalize('NFD','más')))
'ma\u0301s'
```